# I want to open reply textbox after clicking on a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm developing discussion board and I want to make a reply system on each comment using jquery so I can click on a comment link then text box will be opened to write my reply to this comment without loading the whole page.
Here are my Html and PHP code.

```
 <?php
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = '$ArticleID' ");
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
if($rowCount > 0)
{
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
  { 
  $CommentID = $row['comment_id'];
  $Comment = $row['text'];
  ?>
  <li class="comment">
  <div class="comment-container">
  <div class="comment-meta">
  <a class="comment-reply-link link-style3 creply" href="">Reply &raquo;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-body">
  <p><?php echo $Comment; ?>.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </li>

  <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
  <div class="comment_form">
  <form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea class="span10" name="Comment" rows="6"></textarea><br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Reply">
  </form>
  </div> 
 <?php
  }
}
?>
</li>
```

And here is my my jquery code that I have a problem on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $(".creply").click (function(e)
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".comment_form").show(); // problem here...
  //$(".comment_form").show();
  });
  });
</script>
```

When I use the comment line in the script It works but without logic.
On click the link it shows all reply form on all comments not on the separate comment I clicked on. The code above I used $(this) to get the comment I clicked but It doesn't do any actions !??
Any Help, please !!??
I'm using this version of jquery

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
```

[image: Screenshot to my discussion board comments desgin]

Comment: Looks like your closing `</li>` tag on the last line is in the wrong place? i.e. it belongs inside the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query `parents()` and find the next `.comment_form` element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".creply").click (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents().next('.comment_form').toggle();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works :)
I used this line of code 
$(this).parents().next('.comment_form').toggle();
instead of 
$(this).next(".comment_form").show();
and it works .. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey I verified this isn't working, instead I find `$(this).parents().next('li').toggle();` is working. See [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ghx3tu9/2/). Could you provide a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the closest parent with class `.comment` first, then reach the child element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".creply").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.comment').next().show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="comment">
  <div class="comment-container">
    <div class="comment-meta">
      <a class="comment-reply-link link-style3 creply" href="">Reply &raquo;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-body">
      <p>
        MyComment</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li style="list-style: none; display: none">
  <div class="comment_form">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <textarea class="span10" name="Comment" rows="6"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Reply">
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

You can check the modified demo, it's working with multiple comments too:
[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ghx3tu9/1/)